# Is `RefManageR` the new `citr` package in R?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, citations, biblatex

I konw that's kind of a meta question but here it is: Is `RefManageR` the new `citr` package in R?

I am using `citr` since 1 year now and I just realized that it is not maintained on the CRAN anymore (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/citr/index.html). Otherwise, they refer to the package `RefManageR` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RefManageR/index.html).

I am using a bookdown project to compile pdf/html/docx document from Markdown and would like to know if it is compatible

Answer (score 0):

I think they have different purposes:

1. `RefManageR` helps with handling `.bib` files (e.g. if you want to read into R your bibliography collection taken from Zotero). Something like:

```
bib_path <- here::here ("my_folder", "my_bibliography.bib")
# as list
mybib <- RefManageR::ReadBib(bib_path, check = FALSE )
```

2. While `citr`, which is now only available as development version, is a very handy Rstudio Addin that allows you to easily enter a bibliography item in your Bookdown/RMarkdown document - drawing from the .bib file in your environment as shown [here](https://github.com/crsh/citr).